# Writing from TF Dataset to tfrecords file

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tfrecord

It's really easy to read a TFRecords file into a TF Dataset by using a TFRecordDataset, but is there a similar way to write into a TFRecord file given that I already have the info in a Dataset, or do I have to iterate over the dataset and keep serializing examples?